# Using sed to change slash direction in a URL

Tags: bash, macos, sed, terminal

I've seen a few threads about this but nothing I'm trying seems to be working. I'm using terminal within mac to execute this.

I am looking to change back slashes to forward slashes, and I am looking to do so by using the sed command.

My URL thread is basically

`ServerDrive\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\Folder6\Folder7\Folder8\Folder9`

I believe I could use something like `sed -e "s/\\\\/\//"`

However I'm not sure how to tie the entire command in, do I need to start with an echo statement of some sort? As when I glue it all together as

`ServerDrive\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\Folder6\Folder7\Folder8\Folder9 sed -e "s/\\\\/\//"`

Terminal yields an error that reads -bash: ServerDrive: command not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need `echo` and a pipe. Otherwise, the first thing you type on the line is taken as a command to execute -- that's just basic shell syntax.

You also need the `g` modifier to make it replace all the slashes in the line, not just the first one.

```
echo 'ServerDrive\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\Folder6\Folder7\Folder8\Folder9' | sed -e 's#\\#/#g'
```

or you can use a here-string (note that this is a `bash` extension).

```
sed -e 's#\\#/#g' <<< 'ServerDrive\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\Folder6\Folder7\Folder8\Folder9'
```

Also, for a replacement of a single character, you can use `tr` rather than `sed`:

```
tr '\' '/' <<< 'ServerDrive\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\Folder6\Folder7\Folder8\Folder9'
```

If the URL is in a variable, use bash's [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) operator for substring replacement.

```
url='ServerDrive\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\Folder6\Folder7\Folder8\Folder9'
echo "${url//\\//}"
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Barmar - the here-string code ended up being the one that I was looking for and it worked a treat. Out of curiosity if I wanted to learn more about this, what language would you identify that as?

Comment: That's `bash`, the full manual is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr` command ([tr manpage](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/tr1.html)) to replace a set of chars to another

```
echo 'ServerDrive\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\Folder6\Folder7\Folder8\Folder9' | tr '\\' '/'
```

output

```
➜  ~  echo 'ServerDrive\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\Folder6\Folder7\Folder8\Folder9' | tr '\\' '/'
ServerDrive/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/Folder5/Folder6/Folder7/Folder8/Folder9
```